# Extract Multi Values to Points gives ERROR 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, error-999999

I am trying to extract data from a raster based on coordinate points using the Extract Multi Values to Points tool but am repeatedly getting back ERROR 999999. I have ensured both layers are in the same coordinate system (GCS_WGS_1984)and I even clipped the raster file so it is smaller and easier to work with.

I saw that there was a bug with this tool when 64-bit rasters are used but I am using a 32-bit raster.

Any suggestions on what the issue could be?

Comment: What are the parameter values that you are entering when seeing this error?

Comment: I am inputting a xy projection and a raster, the bilinear interpolation is unchecked. Not sure if this answers your questions, i am a newbie at arc

Comment: It's the paths on those inputs that I'm suspicious of.  Use the tool dialog box to execute the tool.  After the tool executes, open the Results window.  Right-click the result and click Copy As Python Snippet.  Use the [edit] button beneath your question body to paste the copied snippet.